# Display rows when scrolling as twitter, using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, twitter

I have a site that displays posts. I want the site's scrolling to behave like twitter - scrolling down will display more and more posts, endlessly.
    Suppose I have the following tables:

A Post table to hold all the posts. Every post is related to a single person

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PublishDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Post] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

A PostTag table to hold all the related tags of each post.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostTag](
    [PostId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PostTag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PostId] ASC,
    [TagId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For each user of the site, the UserPersonStatistics table holds the number of times he showed interest in a person related post.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPersonStatistics](
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPersonStatistics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [PersonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For each user of the site, the UserPostStatistics table holds the number of times he showed interest in a post.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPostStatistics](
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PostId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPostStatistics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [PostId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

For each user of the site, the UserTagStatistic table holds the number of times he showed interest in a tag related post.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTagStatistics](
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserTagStatistics] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [TagId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I need is a stored procedure that for each user returns 35 different posts each time, that "remembers" the last 35 post so it will not return the same posts again, and the 35 posts should be consist of:
15 posts for the most popular tag (UserTagStatistics)
15 posts for the most popular person (UserPersonStatistics)
5 most popular posts (UserPostStatistics)

One problem is that the procedure should return 35 different posts each time.
One more problem is that a post can return once as the most popular post, once as a post of the most popular tag, and once as a post for the most popular person. This post should be counted once, not three times.
The performance of the stored procedure is crucial.

I know its a very complicated question.
Any thoughts are appreciated.

kruvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "LastViewed" datetime field to all tables then use a proc like this.  For performance, just make sure to have an index on UserID+LastViewed+Counter and UserID+PersonID for each of the three tables and it should scream.  Actually, since UserID+LastViewed+Counter is practically the whole table, if possible I'd recommend you make it the [clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on each of your tables so that you avoid creating that second index which would basically be the same size as the raw table.

```
   create proc GetInfo(@UserId bigint) as
    begin
        update userpersonstatistics 
        set 
            lastviewed=getdate() 
        where 
            userid=@UserID and personid in 
                (
                select top 15 personid from userpersonstatistics
                where 
                    userid=@UserID and 
                    (
                    lastviewed is null or lastviewed != 
                        (select max(lastviewed) from userpersonstatistics
                         where userid=@UserID)
                    )    
                order by counter desc
                )


        select * from UserPersonStatistics 
               where UserID=@UserID and LastViewed  = 
            (select max(lastviewed) from UserTagStatistics)

        --**Repeat the above code for UserPostStatistics and UserTagStatistics
    end
```

REVISED PROC BASED ON INPUT:

```
 create proc GetInfo(@UserId bigint) as
    begin
        declare @lastviewed datetime
        declare @results TABLE
        (
          StatType varchar(10),
          Counter int,
          PostID
        )

        set @lastviewed = getdate()

        --Person
        insert into @results(StatType,Counter,PostID)
        select 
            'Person',counter,PostID
        from
            UserPersonStatistics
        where 
            userid=@UserID and personid in 
                (
                select top 35 personid from userpersonstatistics
                where 
                    userid=@UserID and 
                    (
                    lastviewed is null or lastviewed != 
                        (select max(lastviewed) from userpersonstatistics
                         where userid=@UserID)
                    )    
                order by counter desc
                )


        --Post
        insert into @results(StatType,Counter,PostID)
        select 
            'Post',counter,PostID
        from
            UserPostStatistics
        where 
            userid=@UserID and Postid in 
                (
                select top 35 Postid from userPoststatistics
                where 
                    userid=@UserID and 
                    (
                    lastviewed is null or lastviewed != 
                        (select max(lastviewed) from userPoststatistics
                         where userid=@UserID)
                    )    
                order by counter desc
                )


        --Tag
        insert into @results(StatType,Counter,TagID)
        select 
            'Tag',counter,TagID
        from
            UserTagStatistics
        where 
            userid=@UserID and Tagid in 
                (
                select top 35 Tagid from userTagstatistics
                where 
                    userid=@UserID and 
                    (
                    lastviewed is null or lastviewed != 
                        (select max(lastviewed) from userTagstatistics
                         where userid=@UserID)
                    )    
                order by counter desc
                )


        --At this point you could have 105 rows of the various types (35*3).
        --You can use whatever algorithm you need to decide the top 35.
        --That may include some weighting.  
            --You may want to consider using the Rank() function.
    end
```

If your algorithm should consider the #1 top counter from each category before the #2's, take a look at the [Rank() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx).

Comment: Shouldn't the Lastviewed column be added to the Post table? Your code will get me the 15 best match person, tags, and post (and a total of 45, which might contain duplicate posts), but when the user scroll down and a second request for posts is sent, the new posts can still be for the same 15 persons or tags, but just posts with lower counter. Your code will not return posts for the same persons/tags as before, isn't it? I hope i'm clear...

Comment: Suppose I have a person X with counter equals to 10 in UserPersonStatistics table, and a second person Y with a counter equals to 1. Person X has 100 posts in Post tablen and person Y has 40 posts. The code should return all the 100 posts for person X, and only than return posts for person Y, or at least keep a ratio of 10 to 2 between person X and Y. God help me :)

Comment: What happens if there are no PostStats or TagStats counters?  Then do all 35 posts needs to come from PersonStats?  Or situation #2: what if we find 15 PersonStats, 15 PostStats, and 5 TagStats but they're all the same 15 posts?  Do you only return 15 or go back and retrieve more from each of the Stat categories? And which Stats take precedence then to get us to 35?  If, say, I had found 34 unique posts and needed one more, do I get the next post from PostStat, TagStat, or PersonStat?

Comment: 1. If there are no counters then i show whatever posts I want to from Post table. But if there are counters then I have to display posts according to the counters.

Comment: 2. If they are all the same 15 posts then I have to retrieve 20 more posts using the same logic from the stat tables.

Comment: 3. If only 34 posts were found, the last post should be the one with the highest counter. To solve this issue, maybe I should ask for 35 posts from each stat table, and then get only the first 35 distinct posts, and drop all the others.

Comment: @kruvi, I've updated my answer (that hopefully you can accept now!).

Comment: Thanks @sisdog, but suppose i do have the top 35 using your code. All together, they can have 1000 post related to them, becuase one person can have more than one post. If the top person (lets call him John) has 100 posts, your code, as I understand it, will return all the posts for John, while I want 35 posts all together. Moreover, in this case I would like to get only X posts only from John (where x<35), and display posts related to other persons/tags as well. If such a proc will result in bad performance, then maybe I should use your code above. What do you say?

Comment: Don't worry about performance at this point, you need to first figure out your business rules and get the SQL to return what you want it to.  You need to try and code this yourself. SO is here to give you technical assistance, not to write your app for you.  If you can't achieve the results you're looking for then post the query you've written and explain what is wrong with the results.